# can't deploy EAR on JBOSS EAP6

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6, ejb-2.x

I have following error message

```
JBAS014187: N'a pas pu charger la vue EmployeeFacadeLocalHome
```

when i deploy my EAR on JBOSS EAP6
My EAR contains an War and an EJB Module where class EmployeeFacadeLocalHome exist
My Jboss is launched with standalone-full.xml

Regards

```
enter code here11:27:20,096 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS014612: L'opÚration ("add") a ÚchouÚ - adresse : ([{"deployment" => "rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"}]) - description de l'Úchec : {
"JBAS014671: Les services ont ÚchouÚ" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: N'a pas pu traiter la phase POST_MODULE de subdeployment \"webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014187: N'a pas pu charger la vue EmployeeFacadeLocalHome
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EmployeeFacadeLocalHome from [Module \"deployment.rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
"JBAS014771: Services avec des dÚpendances manquantes/non disponibles" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade.Validator [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade.Validator [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade.HandleDelegate [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade.ValidatorFactory [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade.HandleDelegate [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade.ORB [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade.ORB [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".EmployeeFacade] est manquant",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade.ValidatorFactory [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"rr-employee-allinone-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".\"ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\".DepartmentFacade] est manquant"
]
```

}

Comment: Hi another logs

Answer (score 0):

Yes others logs are available here https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2090407/java/plateformes-java-ee-jakarta-ee-spring-serveurs/java-ee/deploiement-d-ejb2-jboss-eap6-4-a/
There is too an zip file with logs
https://www.developpez.net/forums/attachments/p578836d1599630258/java/plateformes-java-ee-jakarta-ee-spring-serveurs/java-ee/deploiement-d-ejb2-jboss-eap6-4/logs2.zip/